# Sqite database insertion in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have an Sqlite database insertion function

```
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put(CardTable.KEY_USERID, card_id);
values.put("id", some id);
values.put("namr", some name);
......
getContentResolver().insert(CardManagingProvider.CONTENT_URI_DETAIL, values);
```

My insert query is not working. Is it because one of the values in `values` is a long string (Base64-encoded form of an image)? Can any one please give me any suggestions?

Comment: What is the error? Post the stacktrace or log output.

Comment: What is `CardTable.KEY_USERID`?  Is it different from your "id" column?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the length limits of SQLite [here](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html).

> The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000). You can raise or lower this value at compile-time using a command-line option like this:
>
> -DSQLITE_MAX_LENGTH=123456789
> The current implementation will only support a string or BLOB length up to 231-1 or 2147483647. And some built-in functions such as hex() might fail well before that point. In security-sensitive applications it is best not to try to increase the maximum string and blob length. In fact, you might do well to lower the maximum string and blob length to something more in the range of a few million if that is possible.

You can determine if your Base64 exceeds those limits, however unlikely it may be.

I would recommend, however, not storing your Base64 string in the database. The larger your database is, the longer it takes for SQL statements to process. It's considered good practice to only store the URI of your image in the database, then use that URI to locate/load your image from disk/web.